# Is there a higher performing implementation of powf(10,floorf(log10f(x)))

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, x86-64, arm64

I have a need to truncate a float to the nearest power of 10. For example, 1.1 would truncate to 1.0 and 4.7e3 would truncate to 1e3. I am currently doing it with the seemingly complicated `powf(10,floorf(log10f(x)))`. I am wondering whether there is a better performing (as in faster execution speed) solution? My target CPU architecture is both x86-64 and arm64.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
  float x = 1.1e5f;
  while (x > 1e-6f)
  {
    float y = powf(10,floorf(log10f(x)));
    printf("%e ==> %g\n", x, y); 
    x /= 5.0f;
  }
}
```

when run, this produces

```
1.100000e+05 ==> 100000
2.200000e+04 ==> 10000
4.400000e+03 ==> 1000
8.800000e+02 ==> 100
1.760000e+02 ==> 100
3.520000e+01 ==> 10
7.040000e+00 ==> 1
1.408000e+00 ==> 1
2.816000e-01 ==> 0.1
5.632000e-02 ==> 0.01
1.126400e-02 ==> 0.01
2.252800e-03 ==> 0.001
4.505600e-04 ==> 0.0001
9.011199e-05 ==> 1e-05
1.802240e-05 ==> 1e-05
3.604480e-06 ==> 1e-06
```

Comment: You're saying both "complicated" and "better performing". So, are you looking for even simpler or do you want faster? Which is more/the most important?

Comment: @CraigEstey is right. I don't think it is possible to write a simpler formula than `powf(10,floorf(log10f(x)))`, and if there is, it will not be fast. Faster implementation is probably possible (are you sure that this formula is a bottleneck in your code?), but for sure will lead to much more complicated code.

Comment: What is the domain that needs to be supported? In particular, how big can `x` be? What accuracy is required? The `log10f` function rounds its results, so `log10f(x)` may return some values for which floor(`log10f(x)`) differs from the mathematical floor(log10(x)). Is that okay?

Comment: A possible optimization way is to use lookup tables. Extracting the exponent from the float, and with a LUT, find the decimal magnitude and possibly the mantissa threshold if between two magnitudes.

Comment: @CraigEstey - I clarified the original question. I am looking for a faster execution.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - It's hard to place absolute limits on x, but I would say that 90% will be between 10 and 1e-2 with the rest being less likely the further away you get from 1

Comment: Is your input always a strictly positive number?

Comment: @TonyK - yes, `x>0` is guaranteed

Comment: how often do you call the function? If you have a list then SIMD and multithread would be one of the ways to speed up

Comment: @phuclv - This is being done at unpredictable intervals, but frequently. It is not clear to me whether SIMD would provide any performance improvement

Comment: Paul Grinberg, 1) Fastest on average or fastest worst case?  2) What should `FLT_TRUE_MIN` return? 0.0f?

Comment: I just did a benchmark. The average time for your equation is ... 88 nanoseconds. And, I believe that is high. So, how much faster do you want it?

Comment: Do you want a string for printing, or do you need the result as a `float` for further calculation?  FP->string conversion is hard (and not super fast), so if you just want printing, better to produce a string directly.

Comment: @PeterCordes - The returned value needs to be a `float` so that further math can be done on that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to use a lookup table to speed up the computation. This technique should work for all **normal** floating point numbers. Subnormal numbers and NaN won't work without some dedicated logic, 0 and infinity can be handled by extreme values in the table.

Although I expect this technique to be actually faster than original implementation, measurements are needed.

The code uses C++20 `std::bit_cast` to extract the exponent from the `float` value. If not available, other older techniques like `frexpf` exist.

```
#include <bit>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>
#include <limits>

constexpr float magnitudeLUT[] = { 
    0.f,    1e-38f, 1e-38f, 1e-38f, 1e-38f, 1e-37f, 1e-37f, 1e-37f, 1e-36f, 1e-36f, 1e-36f, 1e-35f, 
    1e-35f, 1e-35f, 1e-35f, 1e-34f, 1e-34f, 1e-34f, 1e-33f, 1e-33f, 1e-33f, 1e-32f, 1e-32f, 1e-32f, 
    1e-32f, 1e-31f, 1e-31f, 1e-31f, 1e-30f, 1e-30f, 1e-30f, 1e-29f, 1e-29f, 1e-29f, 1e-28f, 1e-28f, 
    1e-28f, 1e-28f, 1e-27f, 1e-27f, 1e-27f, 1e-26f, 1e-26f, 1e-26f, 1e-25f, 1e-25f, 1e-25f, 1e-25f, 
    1e-24f, 1e-24f, 1e-24f, 1e-23f, 1e-23f, 1e-23f, 1e-22f, 1e-22f, 1e-22f, 1e-22f, 1e-21f, 1e-21f, 
    1e-21f, 1e-20f, 1e-20f, 1e-20f, 1e-19f, 1e-19f, 1e-19f, 1e-19f, 1e-18f, 1e-18f, 1e-18f, 1e-17f, 
    1e-17f, 1e-17f, 1e-16f, 1e-16f, 1e-16f, 1e-16f, 1e-15f, 1e-15f, 1e-15f, 1e-14f, 1e-14f, 1e-14f, 
    1e-13f, 1e-13f, 1e-13f, 1e-13f, 1e-12f, 1e-12f, 1e-12f, 1e-11f, 1e-11f, 1e-11f, 1e-10f, 1e-10f, 
    1e-10f, 1e-10f, 1e-09f, 1e-09f, 1e-09f, 1e-08f, 1e-08f, 1e-08f, 1e-07f, 1e-07f, 1e-07f, 1e-07f, 
    1e-06f, 1e-06f, 1e-06f, 1e-05f, 1e-05f, 1e-05f, 1e-04f, 1e-04f, 1e-04f, 1e-04f, 1e-03f, 1e-03f, 
    1e-03f, 1e-02f, 1e-02f, 1e-02f, 1e-01f, 1e-01f, 1e-01f, 1e+00f, 1e+00f, 1e+00f, 1e+00f, 1e+01f, 
    1e+01f, 1e+01f, 1e+02f, 1e+02f, 1e+02f, 1e+03f, 1e+03f, 1e+03f, 1e+03f, 1e+04f, 1e+04f, 1e+04f, 
    1e+05f, 1e+05f, 1e+05f, 1e+06f, 1e+06f, 1e+06f, 1e+06f, 1e+07f, 1e+07f, 1e+07f, 1e+08f, 1e+08f, 
    1e+08f, 1e+09f, 1e+09f, 1e+09f, 1e+09f, 1e+10f, 1e+10f, 1e+10f, 1e+11f, 1e+11f, 1e+11f, 1e+12f, 
    1e+12f, 1e+12f, 1e+12f, 1e+13f, 1e+13f, 1e+13f, 1e+14f, 1e+14f, 1e+14f, 1e+15f, 1e+15f, 1e+15f, 
    1e+15f, 1e+16f, 1e+16f, 1e+16f, 1e+17f, 1e+17f, 1e+17f, 1e+18f, 1e+18f, 1e+18f, 1e+18f, 1e+19f, 
    1e+19f, 1e+19f, 1e+20f, 1e+20f, 1e+20f, 1e+21f, 1e+21f, 1e+21f, 1e+21f, 1e+22f, 1e+22f, 1e+22f, 
    1e+23f, 1e+23f, 1e+23f, 1e+24f, 1e+24f, 1e+24f, 1e+24f, 1e+25f, 1e+25f, 1e+25f, 1e+26f, 1e+26f, 
    1e+26f, 1e+27f, 1e+27f, 1e+27f, 1e+27f, 1e+28f, 1e+28f, 1e+28f, 1e+29f, 1e+29f, 1e+29f, 1e+30f, 
    1e+30f, 1e+30f, 1e+31f, 1e+31f, 1e+31f, 1e+31f, 1e+32f, 1e+32f, 1e+32f, 1e+33f, 1e+33f, 1e+33f, 
    1e+34f, 1e+34f, 1e+34f, 1e+34f, 1e+35f, 1e+35f, 1e+35f, 1e+36f, 1e+36f, 1e+36f, 1e+37f, 1e+37f, 
    1e+37f, 1e+37f, 1e+38f, 1e+38f, std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity() };

float decimalMagnitude(float val)
{
    uint32_t intVal = std::bit_cast<uint32_t>(val);
    uint8_t exponent = intVal >> 23;

    if (val >= magnitudeLUT[exponent + 1])
        return magnitudeLUT[exponent + 1];
    else
        return magnitudeLUT[exponent];
}

int main()
{
    for (float v = 1e-38f; v < 1e38f; v *= 1.78)
        printf("%e => %e\n", v, decimalMagnitude(v));
}
```

Comment: Good idea.  Needs work for wee values: Try `decimalMagnitude(f)` for `FLT_TRUE_MIN <= f <= FLT_MIN` to return `1e-39f, 1e-40f, 1e-41f`,....`

Comment: In my (admittedly limited) testing, a LUT solution is fastest. While I did tag this question with `c++`, I have to support older compilers (e.g. gcc 4.6), so C++20 is not an option. However, the same functionality can be achieved with simple C using `int exponent; frexpf(x, &exponent);`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I know this doesn't work for subnormal floating points. Supporting them would need a special logic.

Comment: @prapin With `frexpf(x, &exponent)`, additional code to support subnormal's is not needed, just a 23 more entries in the table.

Comment: @PaulGrinberg: Or just `memcpy` the float into a `uint32_t`.  (And optionally `static_assert( sizeof(float) == sizeof(uint32_t) )` or whatever simple check you want.)  Then use this directly.  `std::bit_cast<>` isn't magic, it's just convenient syntax for a safe type-pun.  On most compilers including GCC, `memcpy` between same-sized objects is inlined and optimized to not even spill them from registers.  I wouldn't be surprised if the `std::bit_cast` implementation in libstdc++ uses memcpy.

Answer (score 1):

I would say don't sweat it. Unless the program is spending a large proportion of its time doing this truncation, it's not worth optimising what is probably super-fast anyway. But if you wanted to optimise for your common cases (1e-2 <= x <= 10), then you might try using 32-bit integer arithmetic to compare with the binary representations of 1e-2, 1e-1, 1, and 10 (for instance, 1e-1 is 0x3dcccccd) ; if it's outside that range, you can fall back on the floating point version. Only experimentation will determine if this actually runs faster.

Comment: The golden rule of optimization: profile first!